# Git diff gives no output although SHA for image is different

Tags: node.js, git, deployment

I'm trying to create a deployment script which will let me know whether or not I have the latest image of my project deployed on either my master or development branch.

I'm attempting to use git.diff to compare the SHA1 hash of the deployed image against my local repository, and although the hashes are clearly different, git.diff gives me no output. I don't understand what's going on here, since if the SHA1 is different, there must surely be changes to show from git.diff?

This is the code I have written so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/node

// get an exec function from node we can use to run shell commands
const exec = require('util').promisify(require('child_process').exec);

// check the user supplied the folder name of the repo as an arg
if (!process.argv[2]) {
  console.error('argument missing');
  process.exit(1);
}

// initialize our git client using the repo path arg
const git = require('simple-git/promise')("../../" + process.argv[2]);

var projectNameArray = process.argv[2].split(".");
const projectName = projectNameArray[0] + "-" + projectNameArray[1] + "-" + projectNameArray[2] 
console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', 'Your project name is:', projectName);


// use an IIAFE for async/await
(async () => {  


  // run git rev-parse development and
  var devSha1 = await git.revparse(['development']);
  console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', 'devSha1: ', devSha1);
  devSha1 = devSha1.replace(/(\n)/gm,"");

  // run git rev-parse master
  var masterSha1 = await git.revparse(['master']);
  console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', 'masterSha1: ', masterSha1);
  masterSha1 = masterSha1.replace(/(\n)/gm,"");

  // use kubectl to export pods to JSON and then parse it
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(`kubectl get deployment ${projectName} -o json`);  
  const pods = JSON.parse(stdout);
  const imageName = pods.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image;

  //get deployed image has
  const commitHashArray = imageName.split('development-' || 'master-');
  console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', 'Deployed image: ', commitHashArray[1]);

  var diffArray = new Array(devSha1, commitHashArray[1])
  //logic to tell if latest is deployed of if behind
  if (commitHashArray[1] == devSha1){
    console.log('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', 'You have the latest image deployed');
  } else {
    console.log('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', 'You don\'t have the latest image deployed');

    await git.diff(diffArray);
  }

})().then(() => console.log('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', 'Ok')).catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

This gives me the following console output:

```
Your project name is: xxx-xxx-xxx
devSha1:  6a7ee89dbefc4508b03d863e5c1f5dd9dce579b4
masterSha1:  4529244ba95e1b043b691c5ef1dc484c7d67dbe2
Deployed image:  446c4ba124f7a12c8a4c91ca8eedde4c3c8652fd
You don't have the latest image deployed
Ok
```

I'm not sure if I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how git.diff works, or if something else is at play here. The images clearly don't match, so I would love if anyone could explain why there is no output from this function?

Thanks! :)

Comment: I realised I wasn't logging the output -> simple fix is just to change line 50 to console.log(await git.diff(diffArray));